# sql select in many-to-many relation not working as expected, EAV design data-model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, many-to-many

sql select in relation many-to-many not works as expected

i have the following tables in relation many-to-many:

```
table product:
prd_cod (pk)
cat_cod (fk)
prd_nome 

table description_characteristic:
prd_cod(fk)
id_characteristic(fk)
description

table characteristic:
id_characteristic(pk)
name
```

we suppose that the cat_cod will be 1, so i want to show all the products that have the category code equals 1,that will be provided dynamically in php for parameter ...

I have done this select below to solve my problem:

```
select p.prd_cod,p.prd_name,c.name_characteristic,dc.description
from product p,description_characteristic dc, characteristic c
where p.prd_cod = dc.prd_cod and
dc.id_ccharacteristic = c.id_characteristic and
p.cat_cod = 1
```

**but the data were shown this way:**

```
Prd_cod  Prd_name   name_characteristic  descript  
  1          pen        Color            pink      
  1          Pen        manufacturer     kingston  
  1          Pen        type                 brush
  1          Pen        weight               0.020
```

**I want to show the result this way:**

```
Prd_cod  Prd_name   name_characteristic  descript  name_characteristic  descript
  1          pen        Color            pink      type                 brush
  2          Pen-drive  manufacturer     kingston  weight               0.020
```

I would like to show all the characteristics of the same product, and not just two as above...

I can not do a select to solve this
please i need help
Thank you all

Comment: You're using the EAV anti-pattern, which is a generally bad database design. How you approach this particular problem depends a lot on specifics of your situation which you haven't mentioned... can a product have any number of characteristics? Can your front end be changed to handle the data in the first format?

Comment: the product may have n characteristic, and characteristic may have n products, this tree tables its a many-to-many relation, tanks tom

Comment: Your example input and output don't line up. Your input has prd_cod=1 for all rows, but your example output suddenly has a prd_cod=2

Comment: I put the your answer of the question in the main text.

Comment: If you're going to use this structure for a web site like pricegrabber.com, you'd better write a script to generate a pile of meaningless sample data first. My guess is that either performance will be dead slow, or that you won't be able to figure out how to do write queries to generate the simplest web page. (Querying an EAV structure is a lot harder than querying a regularly normalized structure.)

Comment: I am looking for someone who can appreciate my data model and give me some suggestion, if anyone is interested to help me leave the mail that I send the data model, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Tom H., your database layout may generally be a bad idea and you might reconsider it. That said, there is no really clean solution producing the mysql result set you want. But you might use something crazy with GROUP_CONCAT like this, reproducing the real data with some PHP-side postprocessing:

```
SELECT p.prd_cod, p.prd_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name_characteristic), GROUP_CONCAT(dc.description)
from product p,description_characteristic dc, characteristic c
where p.prd_cod = dc.prd_cod and
dc.id_ccharacteristic = c.id_characteristic and
p.cat_cod = 1
GROUP BY p.prd_cod
```

This should return something like

```
Prd_cod  Prd_name   name_characteristic               descript  
  1          pen        Color,manufacturer            pink,Apple
```

this result set should be post-processed like this:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $p = array_combine(
             explode(",", $res["name_characteristic"]),
             explode(",", $res["descript"]));
    $p["prd_cod"] = $res["prd_cod"];
    $out[] = $p;
}
```

I would not call this a robust solution, though - for example, commas in your values screw things up. If you want to avoid madness like this, you'll have to postprocess the result you already get.

But if you want to show some mad sql aggregation skills (and you seem to be interested as you've chosen this database layout), this one is for you.

Comment: Steffen Müller want to thank you for responding promptly, I will test this solution now, this model will be used for a project to a site like pricegrabber.com, which makes comparison of products, the data modeling was done in order to support a large amount of data but do not know if I did right, you have the interest to analyze the data modeling? or has a better suggestion for me?? Thank you very much

Comment: Rather consider buying a book about good database design. stackoverflow is not the place to get your whole database scheme analyzed for free.

Comment: I am still beginner in data modeling, I confess that I will follow your suggestion, thank you steffen ...